# How to create a circular ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a circular `ListView` so that I can dynamically add some items in this... I have read many tutorials and some `StackOverflow` answers, but none of them worked for me...

[image: i have to display name in these boxes..]

Can anybody guide me to create circular list?

Comment: actually whatever i tried just display the data vertically.as listview do normally.i have no idea how to display in circular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **[Android SDK: Creating a Rotating Dialer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)** will help you to create your layout.

You have to modify code yourself to achieve your goal. May be this is a good start for you. :)

[image]